# How to insert two tables side by side in Word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2019

I want to insert two tables side by side on a single page. The tables are pretty large, 46 rows by 4 columns. I created them in Excel, but found that they can't be imported directly and have to be pasted into an existing table (Table > Excel Spreadsheet). I did the same and got them in the document.

Now the problem is that they can't be placed side by side (perfectly). When I do not have any break (section break, page break or even a line break), they do get side by side, but one of them is shifted down by one row. I tried using columns, but it didn't help.

I'm using Office 2019 Version 1905.
The [document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cDj_9rgeHm6ZnVxwRCtwvJ-qpHIzWH02)<sup>1</sup>.
(As the table to the right is shifted down by one row, the last row can't be seen)

Thanks.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some fonts might not be there on your computer.

Comment: Must you embed them as worksheet objects? I find it easier to insert excel items as tables.

Comment: Have you tried embedding the tables in another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click the table, then when you are viewing it as a spreadsheet, you can change the 'window' of cells that are shown in Word. Just grab the bottom to extend it one more line.

[image]

Comment: I just forgot to do this!

Comment: But what if the other table has less rows? I noticed that Word aligns them with their last rows. So one of them (the one with less rows) will be shifted down. What if I want them to be aligned with the top row (so that none of them is shifted down)?

Comment: Word loves to align things on the baseline and it can be difficult to align with the top of objjects. I would probably just add an extra empty row. If you don't want to do that, you can add a 'table' in word with two cells next to each other and top-align them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd get better results formatting the tables as simple word tables (and not as embedded excel files) [There is a description of how to do it in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/652892/how-to-convert-embedded-excel-sheet-to-word-table).

I would then add both tables in a section set to two columns. Remember that the columns are (in Word's world anyway) sequential, so you can change the top alignment by adding or removing paragraph and line breaks to get them to match (assuming they are all in the same paragraph style)

For some reason, it doesn't play nicely when you try and edit the file in google docs, but it does work in word - [downloadable from here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11V9TeGojifvGDEcu16zBkKNYIUG328iG)

Hope this helps